# Why in javascript apply gives different result than direct call?

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code

```
var d = new Date();
Object.prototype.toString(d); //outputs  "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString.apply(d); //outputs "[object Date]"
```

Why is this difference and what's going on?

edit:

```
d.toString() // outputs "Tue Nov 06 2012 ..."
```

So from where does the Date in "[object Date]" comes from. Is it the native code of the browser that do the trick?

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.prototype.toString(d);
```

converts `Object.prototype` to string and ignores its argument. In

```
Object.prototype.ToString.apply(d);
```

`d` gets passed as `this` to the `ToString` method (as if `d.toString()` with `toString` referring to `Object.prototype.toString` was called), which is what the method respects.

See [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`Object#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Yes, because in that case you are calling [`Date.prototype.toString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) not [Object.prototype.toString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) (i.e. Date instances inherit a different `toString` method).

Answer (score 3):

The parameter is ignored in the first call. You are calling the `toString` method on the `Object.prototype` object, basically the same as:

```
{}.toString(); //outputs  "[object Object]"
```

In the second call you are calling the `toString` method for `Object` but applying the `Date` object as its context. The method returns the type of the object as a string, compared the `toString` method of the `Date` object which would instead return the value of the `Date` object as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation is that [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) operates on its `this` object. A function's `this` is set by how you call it so when you do:

```
Object.prototype.toString();
```

the `toString` function's `this` is the `Object.prototype` object. When you call it as:

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(d);
```

its `this` is the object referenced by `d` (a Date object).